# Android circular progress bar with rounded corners

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I am trying to get a circular progress bar with rounded corner as shown below.
[image]

But I am not able to get the rounded corner so far I am able to get the circular progress bar. 
[image]

I am trying to draw it using the xml drawable.

```
 <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/onboarding_activity_progress_bar"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_onboarding_view"
                tools:progress="60"/>
```

Progressbar_onboarding_view.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:useLevel="false"
               android:innerRadiusRatio="2.0"
               android:shape="ring"
               android:thickness="10dp">
            <solid android:color="@color/progress_bar_background_color" />
            <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:useLevel="true"
              android:innerRadiusRatio="2.0"
              android:shape="ring"
              android:thickness="10dp">
            <solid android:color="@color/progress_bar_color" />
        </shape>
        <!--
        <scale
              android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_round_corner"
              android:scaleWidth="98%" /> -->
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

progressbar_rounded_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <corners
         android:radius="10dp"/>

   <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

   <stroke
         android:width="1dp"
         android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

</shape>
```

I tried using scale parameter but the progress corner didn't change. I am not sure how to achieve the rounded corner. Please help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: add corner to in @android:id/progress

Comment: @Pravin I tried it already but it didn't work. It seems corner is only for rectangle shape.

Comment: Try this library for the same :[Progress Widget](https://github.com/lingochamp/MagicProgressWidget)

Comment: @VipulAsri thank you for the suggestion but I don't want to use a third party library. Because I want to be under dex limit and my app is already very close to dex limit.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219455/android-round-edges-on-ring-shaped-progressbar

Comment: u should go for custom progress bar

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo I have posted an answer which might be helpful to you.

Comment: @VipulAsri did you find any solution?

Comment: If it were me, I'd use a GIF. Once in a while, the simplest solution and the best solution are one and the same... BTW if you use this solution, let me know so I can add an answer and get the rep.  ( :

Answer (score 15):

A simple and efficient class extending `View` to draw circular progress, with rounded corners as an option. Progress color, background color, stroke width are also customizable.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.FloatRange

class CircularProgressView : View {
  constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
  constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
  constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

  private val progressPaint: Paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
    style = Paint.Style.STROKE
  }
  private val backgroundPaint: Paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
    style = Paint.Style.STROKE
  }

  private val rect = RectF()
  private val startAngle = -90f
  private val maxAngle = 360f
  private val maxProgress = 100

  private var diameter = 0f
  private var angle = 0f

  override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    drawCircle(maxAngle, canvas, backgroundPaint)
    drawCircle(angle, canvas, progressPaint)
  }

  override fun onSizeChanged(width: Int, height: Int, oldWidth: Int, oldHeight: Int) {
    diameter = Math.min(width, height).toFloat()
    updateRect()
  }

  private fun updateRect() {
    val strokeWidth = backgroundPaint.strokeWidth
    rect.set(strokeWidth, strokeWidth, diameter - strokeWidth, diameter - strokeWidth)
  }

  private fun drawCircle(angle: Float, canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint) {
    canvas.drawArc(rect, startAngle, angle, false, paint)
  }

  private fun calculateAngle(progress: Float) = maxAngle / maxProgress * progress

  fun setProgress(@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 100.0) progress: Float) {
    angle = calculateAngle(progress)
    invalidate()
  }

  fun setProgressColor(color: Int) {
    progressPaint.color = color
    invalidate()
  }

  fun setProgressBackgroundColor(color: Int) {
    backgroundPaint.color = color
    invalidate()
  }

  fun setProgressWidth(width: Float) {
    progressPaint.strokeWidth = width
    backgroundPaint.strokeWidth = width
    updateRect()
    invalidate()
  }

  fun setRounded(rounded: Boolean) {
    progressPaint.strokeCap = if (rounded) Paint.Cap.ROUND else Paint.Cap.BUTT
    invalidate()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for great solution! One clarification question: In `updateRect` method, to get the circles drawn edge to edge, isn't it better to divide obtained `strokeWidth` by 2 before setting rect coordinates? With current setup there are small paddings around the rectangle.

Comment: What language is this written in?

Comment: above program written in Kotlin

Answer (score 12):

Use the `Material CircularProgressIndicator` and use `app:trackCornerRadius="5dp"` to get the curved progress indicator.

```
  <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
            app:indicatorSize="95dp"
            android:progress="60"
            app:trackCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:trackThickness="6dp"
            app:trackColor="@color/track_color"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/yellow_percent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question. But here is a solution which might be helpful to someone else.

This [library](https://github.com/pkleczko/CustomGauge) can be used to achieve this.

Simply add this to your Gradel File

```
compile 'pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge:CustomGauge:1.0.3'
```

And then add this to you XML Layout

```
   <pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.CustomGauge
        android:id="@+id/gauge2"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:gaugeEndValue="100"
        app:gaugePointEndColor="@color/md_blue_800"
        app:gaugePointStartColor="@color/md_blue_300"
        app:gaugeStartAngle="180"
        app:gaugeStartValue="0"
        app:gaugeStrokeCap="ROUND"
        app:gaugeStrokeColor="@color/md_grey_400"
        app:gaugeStrokeWidth="10dp"
        app:gaugeSweepAngle="360" />
```

And this is how you can set the progress of the bar

```
private CustomGauge gauge;// Declare this variable in your activity

gauge = findViewById(R.id.gauge2);//And this on you OnCreate method

gauge.setValue(progress);// Set the progress like this.
```

The library is Opensource and is available to use under the `General Public License, version 2`

Answer (score 1):

Library

```
compile 'pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge:CustomGauge:1.0.4'
```

XML CODE

```
<pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.CustomGauge
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimens_550px"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimens_550px"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/lottie_empty"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/lottie_empty"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/lottie_empty"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/lottie_empty"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"


            app:gaugePointEndColor="#3DEBFF"
            app:gaugePointStartColor="#246887"
            app:gaugeStartAngle="270"
            app:gaugeStrokeCap="ROUND"
            app:gaugeStrokeColor="#80777777"
            app:gaugeStrokeWidth="10dp"
            app:gaugeSweepAngle="360"
            
            />
```

Code java

```
private CustomGauge gauge;// Declare this variable in your activity
gauge = findViewById(R.id.gauge2);//And this on you OnCreate method
gauge.setEndValue(max_progress);// Set the max progress like this.
gauge.setValue(progress);// Set the progress like this.
```

[Image from my apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4g90.png)