# how to create a gradient arc with rounded edges?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to make a progress bar with a donut shape with rounded edges, looking like this:

[image]

I tried this so far:

**ProgressBar in XML :**

```
<ProgressBar style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/shape_ring_gradient"
    android:rotation="-90.0"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar" />
```

**shape_ring_gradient.png :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.17391304"
    android:thicknessRatio="25.0"
    android:useLevel="true">

    <gradient
        android:endColor="#FE000A"
        android:gradientRadius="1000"
        android:startColor="#EB288B"
        android:angle="180"
        android:type="linear" >
    </gradient>

</shape>
```

**Java code:**

```
ProgressBar progressBar = getView().findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
progressBar.setProgress(82);
```

Result :

[image]

Now my question is, how can I :

- Make the ring thicker?
- Round the edges?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: refer this:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219455/android-round-edges-on-ring-shaped-progressbar

Comment: Got it working playing around with this: https://github.com/korre/android-circular-progress-bar