# How to make progressbar progress rounded from edge?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am making custom progressbar with round shape and gradient color. I achieved it but making it rounded from edges is not working.

**This is my progressbar**

```
  <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="80"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bg_progressbar_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**And here is the drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="15dp" >
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#e62a77"
                android:endColor="#d5302a"
                android:startColor="#ff006d"
                android:type="sweep" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

I used `<corners android:radius="8dp"/>` still it's not working.

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219455/android-round-edges-on-ring-shaped-progressbar) May help ..

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="270" android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.55"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="15dp"
                android:useLevel="true">
                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="#e62a77"
                    android:endColor="#d5302a"
                    android:startColor="#ff006d"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="211dp">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="1000"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="7dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#ff006d" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate>
            <inset android:insetBottom="211dp">
                <shape
                    android:innerRadiusRatio="1000"
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:thickness="7dp"
                    android:useLevel="false">
                    <solid android:color="#d5302a" />
                </shape>
            </inset>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56905735/6997819

It uses three items

1) Circle at starting point

2) Circle that moves along progress

3) The main progress route

Check result Image

[image]

Comment: nope it doesn't work. dot on start and end not align properly. I cannot assign fix dp for android:bottom and android:insetBottom

Comment: Somewhere you have to fix that. As per your layout requirement you can make changes accordingly

Comment: Ok adjusted , but what about color? i used gradient color for secondary progress and we are providing solid color for dots. It mismatch on different progress