# Draw circle on start and end point of an Arc

Tags: android, view, draw, android-custom-view, ondraw

Hi im having difficulties on drawing dots on arc's both ends (start and end)

Although I can draw arc on canvas. Heres my sample code for drawing arc.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    float width = (float) getWidth();
    float height = (float) getHeight();
    float radius;

    if (width > height) {
        radius = height / 4;
    } else {
        radius = width / 4;
    }

    float center_x, center_y;
    final RectF oval = new RectF();

    center_x = width / 2;
    center_y = height / 2;

    oval.set(center_x - radius,
            center_y - radius,
            center_x + radius,
            center_y + radius);

    float percent = 25;
    float arcRadius = 360;
    float angle = arcRadius * (percent/100);

    canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, 360, false, trackpaint);
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, angle, false, arcPaint);  
}
```

the only missing is putting circles on start and end points of the arc. I've tried this link but it doest work [Calculate Arc Center Point, Knowing It's Start and End Degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882903/calculate-arc-center-point-knowing-its-start-and-end-degrees). Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**the coordinate of the start point is:**

```
double startX = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(270)) * radius + center_x;

double startY = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(270)) * radius + center_y;
```

**the coordinate of the end point is:**

```
double endX = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(270 + angle)) * radius + center_x;

double endY = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(270 + angle)) * radius + center_y;
```

**and then you can draw circle using the start point and end point:**

```
canvas.drawCircle(startX, startY, 10, paint);

canvas.drawCircle(endX, endY, 10, paint);
```

Comment: If I can only give you a hundred thumbs up, I would do. Either thanks, been spending a couple of hour here. Cheers @7heaven

Comment: @Sheychan not sure what "no perfect circles" means, but if you need to find the start point and end point or any point on the curve(or anything else that is drawn with a Path class). PathMeasure class is what you need.

Comment: @7heaven I mean, will this work on ovals with the bounds of the Rect is rectangle (ex. (20,10,20,10)). <- not perfect circle since perfect circle is drawn by square Rect(10,10,10,10)

Comment: @7heaven Hi! I tried your approach, could you provide any input as to how to do the same for a 'line'?

Comment: @user2511882 you can always use PathMeasure for any shapes draw by Path class

Answer (score 0):

1. Get path from the ARC
2. Use PathMeasure class to retrieve Path length and path TAN, using starting or Ending X and Y coordinates of the ARC
3. Use this X and Y coordinates to draw circle.

Example for circle at the start of the ARC:

```
final Path mPath = new Path();
mPath.addArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle);
PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(mPath, false);
float[] xyCoordinate = { arcStarting.x , arcStarting.y };
float pathLength = pm.getLength();
pm.getPosTan(0, xyCoordinate, null);//"0 for starting point"
PointF point = new PointF(xyCoordinate[0], xyCoordinate[1]);
canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 10, YourPaintHere)
```